# Get List Item Version History for each item if specific field was changed

Tags: list, splistitem, version-history

I have a list that has versioning turned on.  Three of the fields are multi-line text boxes which have appending turned on.  I want to iterate thru each item in the version history and look for changes in those 3 fields only and export to an excel spreadsheet, grouped by item number, sorted by version -descending. I need to include the current version as well.

If I can't get it broken down that much, then I'll take all versions of each item and I can filter using Excel.  I would like to do this with Powershell as I am limited in how I can access the data.  One of the first problems I will need to overcome is accessing our secured site (https:).

Output to look similar to this:
Item#   Version    Field1     Field2    Field3    ModifiedDate   ModifiedBy

I am a accelerated novice:-)  so if you post code, please tell me where I need to replace code with my information.

I thank you for any help anyone can provide!!!!  I have been stuck for months:-(

Comment: Good Queston! This question save my some time!

Answer (score 4):

Here is the sample PowerShell code which can be used to export version history to Excel:

```
# ******* Variables Section ******************
#Define these variables
$WebURL="http://sharepoint.crescent.com/sites/Sales/"
$ListName ="Invoice"
$ReportFile = "D:\Invoice_VersionHistory.csv"
# *********************************************

#delete file if exists
If (Test-Path $ReportFile)
 {
 Remove-Item $ReportFile
 }

#Get the Web and List
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
$List = $web.Lists.TryGetList($ListName)

 #Check if list exists
 if($List -ne $null)
 {
  #Get all list items
  $ItemsColl = $List.Items

  #Write Report Header
  Add-Content -Path $ReportFile -Value "Item ID, Version Lable, Created by, Created at, Title"

  #Loop through each item
  foreach ($item in $ItemsColl)
  {
   #Iterate each version
      foreach($version in $item.Versions)
       {
    #Get the version content
    $VersionData = "$($item.id), $($version.VersionLabel), $($version.CreatedBy.User.DisplayName), $($version.Created), $($version['Title'])"
    #Write to report
    Add-Content -Path $ReportFile -Value $VersionData
   }
  }
 }
Write-Host "Version history has been exported successfully!"
```

Read more: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/06/sharepoint-version-history-export-to-excel.html#ixzz3IACx0Ojy

I have also developed a codeplex project for export version history. You can have a look at it here:
https://exportversionhistory.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks Nadeem, but I am getting an error:  Get-SPWeb : The term 'Get-SPWeb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\hu5c\Desktop\ExtractVersionHistoryScript.ps1:14 char:8
+ $Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
+        ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (Get-SPWeb:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId: CommandNotFoundException        I have SharePoint 2010 and I noticed on your post it said 2013

Comment: This may be because you are running the script in windows Powershell. You will need to load sharepoint snap in.  Or else directly run the script in sharepoint Powershell

Comment: How can we get the updated columns in the Version History? Like Title, Modified Time i.e Which columns are updated those?