# How can we read version history of document library and update particular version (few fileds) data in Sqlserver database?

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, document-library, powershell, version-history

I want to read version history of document library.

and update few fields data of a particular version history in sqlserver table.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Microsoft does not support any changes from database  , so it's heavily recommended to avoid any changes via database

Comment: Thanks M.Qassas, I need to update to Sqlserver database (my own db) but not content database. I need to store version history data (few fields only) in my sql table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `versions history` fields via SQL

- Open SQl Management Studio > Connect to your SharePoint server.
- Navigate to  Content database like `[WSS_Content]`.
- Create a new query from > right click Design Query in Editor > Select `[dbo].[AllDocVersions]` table `inner join` `[AllDocs]` table **on** Doc `ID`, select your required fields to show.

the Query should look like with your required fields

```
SELECT        AllDocVersions.Id, AllDocVersions.UIVersion, AllDocs.DirName, AllDocs.LeafName
FROM            AllDocs INNER JOIN
                         AllDocVersions ON AllDocs.Id = AllDocVersions.Id
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:**

Microsoft does not support any changes from the database , so it's heavily recommended to avoid any changes via the database.

**[update]**

Below is a PowerShell code which can be used to export version history to Excel [Ref](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/120049/get-list-item-version-history-for-each-item-if-specific-field-was-changed)

```
# ******* Variables Section ******************
#Define these variables
$WebURL="http://sharepoint.crescent.com/sites/Sales/"
$ListName ="Invoice"
$ReportFile = "D:\Invoice_VersionHistory.csv"
# *********************************************

#delete file if exists
If (Test-Path $ReportFile)
 {
 Remove-Item $ReportFile
 }

#Get the Web and List
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
$List = $web.Lists.TryGetList($ListName)

 #Check if list exists
 if($List -ne $null)
 {
  #Get all list items
  $ItemsColl = $List.Items

  #Write Report Header
  Add-Content -Path $ReportFile -Value "Item ID, Version Lable, Created by, Created at, Title"

  #Loop through each item
  foreach ($item in $ItemsColl)
  {
   #Iterate each version
      foreach($version in $item.Versions)
       {
    #Get the version content
    $VersionData = "$($item.id), $($version.VersionLabel), $($version.CreatedBy.User.DisplayName), $($version.Created), $($version['Title'])"
    #Write to report
    Add-Content -Path $ReportFile -Value $VersionData
   }
  }
 }
Write-Host "Version history has been exported successfully!"
```

Comment: Can someone please suggest how can I read version history data using powershell or c#?

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your new request,  hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks  M.Qassas, it helped me, But I couldn't get other columns data. I added $($version['ColName']) after $($version['Title']). I'm getting the title column but not other column data. The other column has this value" ROM_STYLE" in csv file.

Comment: it should retrive this column "$($item.id), $($version.VersionLabel), $($version.CreatedBy.User.DisplayName), $($version.Created), $($version['Title']) , so make sure that you already have versions for your items and versions enabled on the list , please don't hestitate to ask me for more clarafication , I am here to help you

Comment: Hi  @M.Qassas, Thanks for your support.                                                    I am able to retrieve columns "$($item.id), $($version.VersionLabel), $($version.CreatedBy.User.DisplayName), $($version.Created), $($version['Title'])  data successfully. But I need to access columns other than "Title". I'm getting null values for other columns.