# Get List Item Version History for each item With PowerShell SharePoint 2010

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, development, powershell

I have gone through the following references -
[Refernce 1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/120049/get-list-item-version-history-for-each-item-if-specific-field-was-changed#answers-header) [Refernce 2](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190021/exporting-item-list-version-history#answers-header)

Those are perfect for the Version History Title and VersionLabel, Created By.
But I need to get the only columns which are updated in the Version 1, 2 and so on.
That is I need to get the only updated columns as per version, not all the columns in the version.

I did the following code to print those as-

> Write-Host "$($version.VersionLabel), $($item.id),
> $($version['Title']), $($version['Category1']), $($version['Reason2']),
> $($version['Code2']), $($version['Assignedto12']),
> $($version['Contact13']), $($version['Borrower14']),
> $($version['Branch16']), $($version['DueDate12']),
> $($version['EmployeeError19'])"

So how can I get the only updated column values, instead of getting all the columns values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get only the values which have changed from previous version, you need to keep track of previous version and compare the field values in current version.

Comment: Do you mean it will take lot of time to perform the export or to write the code? I am not aware of any other alternative.

Comment: No, I mean while importing to the list. It'll take a lot off time to compare with the previous version, So is there anything else to achive this?

Comment: If you look at documentation of `SPListItemVersion`, you will not find anything which will help in accomplishing that, unless I am missing something. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemversion_members(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: OK, How to get the Peopele Field & the Multiline Field in a single cells of Excell File?